# .htaccess RewriteRule country codes and urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ca/(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1&c=ca [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^fr/(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1&c=fr [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In order to achieve the following effect:

```
http://xyz.com/ca/test -> http://xyz.com/index.php?p=test&c=ca
http://xyz.com/fr/test -> http://xyz.com/index.php?p=test&c=fr
http://xyz.com/test    -> http://xyz.com/index.php?p=test
```

But it is failing with a server error. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RewriteCond` conditions only apply to the `RewriteRule` that immediately follows the condition(s). Your last 2 rules don't have any conditions on them and the rules are looping. Just add the 2 conditions in front of the last 2 rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ca/(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1&c=ca [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^fr/(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1&c=fr [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That fixed it! That said, http://xyz.com/ca converts to http://xyz.com/index.php?p=ca&c= under this scenario. How could I cover this case?

Comment: Can it be rewritten so it can be used for any country code. I don't want to go and create a huge htaccess file for every country code.